# Missed environment variables in Eclipse Juno

Tags: 12.04, unity, eclipse

I recently moved from Eclipse Indigo to Juno.

I installed the IDE in my Ubuntu 12.04 by downloading the archive from [here](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/). Then I created an entry in the unity launcher for Juno as I done before for Indigo. Here is what I wrote in `~/.local/share/applications/eclipse-juno.desktop`:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Name=Eclipse Juno
Comment=Eclipse Integrated Developmentm Environment
Icon=~/.eclipse-juno/icon.xpm
Exec=~/.eclipse-juno/eclipse -vmargs -Duser.name="my name" 
Terminal=false
Categories=Development;IDE;Java;
```

When I run eclipse from the unity launcher, eclipse does not see environment variables that I set in ~/.bascrc. Instead, if I run eclipse from shell, it can see all the env variables.

How can I fix the problem?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Do you have any solution for that, yet?

Comment: No, I'm sorry. Currently I changed both the OS(13.04) and Eclipse(Kepler) version and the problem does not appear anymore.